# Passing argument to decorator from controller in Rails using Draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, draper

I couldn't figure out how to pass an argument to a decorator from a controller:

The decorator:

```
def as_json(options = nil)
  {
   :name => user.name,
   :dob => user.dob
   :created_at => user.created_at,
   :url => user
  }
end
```

The controller:

```
format.json { render :json => UserJsonDecorator.new(@user)}
```

Just passing an extra argument to the new method does not work:

```
UserJsonDecorator.new(@user,options)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was basically using it wrong.

correct form to pass additional arguments is:

```
UserJsonDecorator.new(@user).to_json(options)
```